# Fetch Different Values in different column for a specific id

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a data as shown below:

[image]

I want the output as shown below

[image]

in Postgress or in Excel.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! What is the maximum number of people per loan?

Comment: Don't do it with SQL, this is much better done in a tool like Excel - but a question how to do a "crosstab" in Excel is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) to convert to an array of names and then access names by index to get your desired output.

```
WITH loan_names AS (
    SELECT loan_id
         , array_agg(customer_name) AS names
      FROM loan
     GROUP BY loan_id
)
SELECT loan_id
     , names[1] customer_name_1
     , names[2] customer_name_2
     , names[3] customer_name_3
  FROM loan_names
;
```

SQL does not allow for a variable number of columns, so you will need to decide how many names you want maximum. In this example you get a maximum of three. Adding `names[4]` would add a fourth, etc.